# Mapstruct <abstract main type>/<sub types> to <abstract main type Dto>/<subtypes> Mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

We want to map

```
abstract Person
    PersonRole1 extends Person
    PersonRole2 extends Person
```

to

```
abstract PersonDto
   PersonDtoRoleX extends PersonDto
   PersonDtoRoleY extends PersonDto
   PersonDtoRoleZ extends PersonDto
```

The mapper would get Person Type as parameter (either `PersonRole1` or `PersonRole2`). Depending on the properties of that parameter it should decide to which Dto Type to map (one of `PersonDtoRoleX` , `PersonDtoRoleY`, `PersonDtoRoleZ`).

What would be the best way to structure the mapstruct mapper definition?

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct is not intended to solve all the business problems you have, so you possibly need to implement your own piece of logic in a method. MapStruct will call that method from its generated code. You might want to play around with `@TargetType`.  [See here for an example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/ap/test/references/ReferencedCustomMapper.java).

And you could call MapStruct generated methods from within your own logic.